# (Mongoose Model) is not a constructor error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Thanks in advance for your attention on this trivial problem that I'm totally stumped on. I'm working on the FreeCodeCamp Node.js and MongoDB projects, and am having trouble with a Mongoose model. Here is the POST handler that's causing the issue:

```
const User = require('./models/user')

...

app.post('/api/exercise/new-user', (req, res) => {
      var newUser = new User({name: req.body.username});
      console.log("newUser", newUser);
      newUser.save();
      res.json({
        message: "New user created!",
        username: newUser.name,
        user_id: newUser._id
      });
    })
```

And here is `user.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.User = mongoose.model("User", new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
}));
```

What happens when I make a POST request at that `/api/exercise/new-user`, is my browser simply displays text saying `User is not a constructor`. [Here is the Glitch project in it's entirety](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jade-precious-falcon) so you can see the rest of the context (there isn't a whole lot). If you show the app in Glitch and use the "Create new user" input you'll be able to recreate the issue. As far as I can tell I don't have any weird little capitalization mistakes, but of course that's something you miss all the time!

As a secondary question, how is it that the way I'm seeing this is that it shows up in the browser as simply that string, and not in my console or something like that? So far the only response that I understand I'm sending is that JSON, how is that string making its way there at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was something very simple! In my `server.js` file where I'm handling the POST request, I simply didn't import the User model correctly, I went from this:

```
const User = require('./models/user')
```

To this:

```
const { User } = require('./models/user')
```

Whoops! Hopefully this can give someone else an idea of what could be going wrong in their own code if they come across this.